# Persisting sub-classes with DynamoDB in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a class hierarchy that I would like to persist with DynamoDB's .NET object persistence model (V2 entry conversion). I would like to persist derived classes to the same table as the base class, and then be able to query all entries in that table and have them deserialize to the appropriate derived types.

In most ORMs, you would be able to specify a type discriminator column that it would use to decide what subtype to deserialize into.

Code example:

```csharp
public abstract class Animal
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DynamoDBTable("Animal")]
public sealed class Dog : Animal
{
    public double Loyalty { get; set; }
}

[DynamoDBTable("Animal")]
public sealed class Cat : Animal
{
    public int MiceEaten { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
        using (var context = new DynamoDBContext(client, new DynamoDBContextConfig {Conversion = DynamoDBEntryConversion.V2}))
        {
            context.Save(new Dog { Name = "Rover", Loyalty = 0.8 });
            context.Save(new Cat { Name = "Felix", MiceEaten = 14 });

            var doggie = context.Load<Animal>("Rover");
            var pussy = context.Load<Animal>("Felix");

            Console.WriteLine(doggie.GetType().Name); // should output Dog
            Console.WriteLine(pussy.GetType().Name); // should output Cat
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output would be:

```
Dog
Cat
```

But actually crashes with the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 
Type ConsoleApplication1.Animal is unsupported, it cannot be instantiated
```

Is there a nice way of persisting this class hierarchy? I am able to make changes to the class model if required, I just want it to feel like idiomatic C#.

I have also tried various combinations of where I put the DynamoDBTable attribute, including just on Animal and on all three classes. If I remove the abstract from Animal, it doesn't throw an exception, but instead it outputs Animal Animal and therefore doesn't deserialize the properties specific to the derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same problem right now.  As far as I can tell, DynamoDB doesn't provide first-class support for mapping row data from a single table to different C# classes.

There's an issue posted in the GitHub `aws-sdk-net` repository ([#245](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/245#issuecomment-140202666)) that shows how one might use a type discriminator approach to deserializing table rows to different C# classes.  That's what I'm going to start investigating... if it works out, I'll update my answer here.

**UPDATE #1**: Unfortunately, it seems the only way to deserialize DynamoDB data to the appropriate subclass type is type mapping -- that is, build a set of type checks that cast your DynamoDB to the matching concrete type.